# C# WCF service client with BinarySecurityToken in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-5, wcf-security

I have a .NET 5 application that is required to call a WCF service that uses a `wsse:BinarySecurityToken` header element to carry an auth token obtained from a separate service.

I've got a WSDL and the generated client classes from that.

There are no other security headers present, as shown here (some identifying values removed):

```
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="Something" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-SomeGUID" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">Token value goes here</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
```

I've spent some time googling this but the only reference to BinarySecurityToken that seems to be suited for use with a SOAP Client generated from a WSDL refers to .NET 2.0.

I can't find anything in [.NET 5 WCF](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf) that looks like it could add this.
Am I just going to have to build my own header/envelope, serialise the classes generated from the WSDL into XML and then just jam it into my hand built XML and POST it to the WCF service? It's a valid solution but is a bit icky.

Unfortunately the service we are calling cannot be changed as it's a third party service.

Comment: Icky or not, this could be your only chance.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I've done icky before, but it is always checking to see if a cleaner solution is possible.

Comment: WCF is not fully supported in .NET 5. There are many features in WCF that are not supported in .NET 5. For more information about it, you can refer to this link: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md